# cron job that kills a process after 5 hours

Tags: php, cron

I basically have a cron job which runs every night that updates thousands of products in my database.

The reason I run the cron job at night is because there will be less latency on the servers as not many people visit the site during this time, the cron job can pretty much run on for days without any interference.

Here is what the cron job command looks like

```
30 23 * * *     /usr/bin/php /var/www/ul/prices_all.php >> /var/www/ul/log/prices_all.txt
```

What I would like to know is would it be possible to create a cron job which kills this process after 5 hours e.g.

```
30 05 * * *     kill /var/www/ul/prices_all.php[process]
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this with timeout (coreutils):

```
30 23 * * *   timeout 18000  /usr/bin/php /var/www/ul/prices_all.php >> /var/www/ul/log/prices_all.txt
```

It simply sets a timeout (18000secs = 5 hours) and kills the process if it is still running after that time.

Or you can set a timeout in the php file itself:

```
<?php set_time_limit(18000);
```

Comment: 60 (sec) * 60 (min) = 3,600 sec (1 hour).
9000 is unlikely to be 5 hours, unless I made a mistake.

Comment: I would prefer to control the timeouts in crontab since I have so many cron jobs

Comment: @GreenBlack How about in python? can we use method timeout?

Comment: Have tried this `*/2 * * * * timeout -s 9 60 cd /usr/etc && python2.6 hello.py 10.10.252.120 437 >> res.txt` and not working

Comment: because you have the timeout on the cd command - which happens instantly. move the timeout -s 9 60 part after the && and before the python2.6 part.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could create a cronjob that killed the process 5 hours later. There are a few decent ways to do this. For instance, you could have the first script write its pid (you can get it with [getmypid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php)) to a file when it starts up and then have the second cron job read that pid and kill it. This would work, but is pretty inelegant.

A more elegant method would be setting an [execution limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) in the script itself if your PHP config allows it (ie, is not in safe mode).